# Receive message either from ServerHealthKafka or ServerHealthSap type

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have the following type definition:

```
object ServerMonitoring {

  sealed trait ServerHealthKafka

  case object KafkaInactiveConfirmed extends ServerHealthKafka

  case object KafkaActiveConfirmed extends ServerHealthKafka

  sealed trait ServerHealthSap

  case object SapInactiveConfirmed extends ServerHealthSap

  case object SapActiveConfirmed extends ServerHealthSap

}
```

and I would like to create an actor that accept either `ServerHealthKafka` or `ServerHealthSap`.

I've started to create but I do not know how to continue:

```
object DetectorStateMachine {

  case class State(kafka: ServerHealthKafka, sap: ServerHealthSap)

  def create(informant: ActorRef[InformantEvent]): Behavior[ServerHealthEvent] =
    Behaviors.setup { context =>

      context.log.info(s"=============> Start DetectorStateMachine <=============")

      def loop(state: State): Behavior[ServerHealthEvent] = {

        Behaviors.receiveMessage {
          case KafkaActiveConfirmed =>
          case KafkaInactiveConfirmed =>
          case SapActiveConfirmed
          case SapInactiveConfirmed =>
        }

      }

      loop(State(KafkaInactiveConfirmed, SapInactiveConfirmed))


    }

}
```

Do I have to use here the message adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The `Behavior` takes a single message type, so you need to define a common `trait` for all messages:

```
sealed trait ServerHealthEvent
sealed trait ServerHealthKafka extends ServerHealthEvent
sealed trait ServerHealthSap extends ServerHealthEvent
```